# Authorize attribute doesn't work in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, roles

I have a User with a role of `Member`. I have this Login Action:

```
public virtual ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl))
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
    }
    return View();
}
```

And I have this ActionMethod :

```
[Authorize(Roles="Member")]
public virtual ActionResult PostLostThing()
{
    var maingroups = _maingroups.SelectAll();
    var Provinces = _provinces.SelectAll();
    ViewBag.MainGroups = new SelectList(maingroups, "GroupId", "GroupName", maingroups.FirstOrDefault().GroupId);
    ViewBag.SubGroups = new SelectList(maingroups.FirstOrDefault().SubGroups, "id", "name");
    ViewBag.Provinces = new SelectList(Provinces, "Id", "Title", Provinces.FirstOrDefault().Id);
    ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(Provinces.FirstOrDefault().Cities, "Id", "Name");

    return View();
}
```

When user is logged in and call view `PostLostThing` it redirects to Login Page, but when the `Role` of  `Authorize` attribute is removed, it works very well. I have this `SetAuthCookie` method:

```
private void SetAuthCookie(string memberName, string roleofMember, bool presistantCookie)
{
    var timeout = presistantCookie ? FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes : 30;

    var now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
    var expirationTimeSapne = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout);

    var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1,
        memberName,
        now,
        now.Add(expirationTimeSapne),
        presistantCookie,
        roleofMember,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
        );

    var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

    var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
        Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
    };

    if (FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain != null)
    {
        authCookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
    }

    if (presistantCookie)
        authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);

    Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're setting the auth cookie yourself, you need to implement the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` in the Global.asax.cs file. Otherwise, nothing beyond the user name is added to the Principal object.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        string[] roles = null;

        GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), roles);
        Context.User = userPrincipal;
    }
}
```

The overload you're using assumes that the value you've passed `roleofMember` is actually some serialized data. You then need to tell it how to handle deserializing that user data. Since you're just passing a single role name, you can amend the sample above to:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        string[] roles = new string [] { authTicket.UserData };

        GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), roles);
        Context.User = userPrincipal;
    }
}
```

Comment: I getting `""` for userData . ??

Comment: Are you calling the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` method at any point, somewhere else in the code? Have you verified that `roleofMember` has a value when you're creating the cookie?